# Sanctuary is gone, but how do I get to Moxxi's radio?

Tags: borderlands-2

Does anyone know how to get back/ what mission to do to get  Sanctuary 'back' , so I can place the AI in Moxxie's radio?

Comment: Continue the story.  You'll get back to Sanctuary eventually.

Answer (score 7):

Once you've

> completed the Rising Action quest (and Sanctuary teleports away)

you will be unable to reach Sanctuary until

> you've completed the Bright Lights, Flying City quest. The good news is that it's the very next quest in that chain, so you're not cut off for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Some quest will have a status of "Blocked" and you won't be able to continue (or select them) at all until you find Sanctuary again.

Comment: This actually doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: Seems like im in some kind of deadlock, I cannot take on another mission ..

Comment: @user52067 are you sure? There should be a main mission in your quest log (denoted by a Vault symbol), just select that and continue and things will happen.

Comment: @user52067 You should be able to take any number of missions. If it shows up as blocked it probably means you haven't advanced the story enough to continue.